# scanf() changing the value of matrix's index

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int i, j, vet [1][1];

for (i=0; i<2; i++){
    for (j=0; j<2; j++){
        scanf ("%d", &vet[i][j]); //input values for each position
        printf("\nvet[%d][%d] = %d", i, j, vet[i][j]); //print the entire matrix
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

> INPUT:
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> OUTPUT:
>
> 1 2 3
>
> 4 5 6
>
> 7 8 0

The code is attributing the value of 9 to 'j' instead of vet [ i ][ j ], which would correspond to vet [2][2]. Therefore, I'm getting vet [2][9] = 0 in the last  printed item. 
Why this happens?

Comment: How many elements does a matrix defined as `int vet [1][1];` have?

Comment: You're right. The code I had copied was a previous version of what I had in mind. Just fixed that.

Comment: ___Please do not change the question after an answer has been provided. You can always add comments for further discussion, but changing the querstion makes the answers invalid.___

Comment: @TheTourist Even with the modified code, you have same problem - 2 array elemnts, and you're trying to use `2` as index, whereas the only valid indexes would have been 0 and 1 there.

Comment: That's it. That made me figure it out. The problem relies in the fact that I was thinking that declaring an array vet[2] would create an array with the interval [0,2], i.e., 3 elements — the reason for the loop having such a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an array defined like

```
 int vet [1][1];
```

the only valid index is `0`, i.e, `vet[0][0]`. Using index value 1 makes out of bound access. Hence, in the very second iteration of the inner loop, for the first iteration of the outer loop, you're trying to access out of bound memory, which invokes undefined behavior. Then on, the behavior is - well, undefined. You cannot justify the output, if any.

In case you want to have an array of arrays with 2 members, you got to change the definition to

```
int vet [2][2];
```

**<sup>*Note: Suggested to change the array dimension, as otherwise, the loop itself does not make sense, if you got only one element. You can surely make the code valid by making the loop terminating condition `i < 1` and `j < 1`, but in that case, the loop renders meaningless.*</sup>**